# MUI Autocomplete doesn't work with react-hook-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

**Issue summary**

I get different errors at different times. When I select a suggested option, I get the following error and warning:

`Material-UI: The getOptionLabel method of Autocomplete returned undefined instead of a string for 0`

`Material-UI: The value provided to Autocomplete is invalid. None of the options match with 0`

Plus, the option doesn't get selected and the input becomes undefined. However, when trying to choose a value a second time, it gets selected (but still shows the errors).

When I clear the input I get this error:

```
A component is changing the controlled value state of Autocomplete to be uncontrolled.
Elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa).
Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled Autocomplete element for the lifetime of the component.
The nature of the state is determined during the first render, it's considered controlled if the value is not `undefined`.
```

***Code for the autocomplete component***

```
const AutocompleteUnit = ({control, label, name, ...rest}) => {

  return (
    <>
      <Controller
        onChange={([,data]) => data}
        name={name}
        as={
          <Autocomplete
          {...rest}
          autoHighlight
          style={{marginTop: "25px"}}
          getOptionLabel={option => option.label}
          renderInput={params => (
            <TextField
              {...params}
              label={label}
              variant="outlined"
            />
          )}
        />
        }
        control={control}
        defaultValue={rest.options[0]}
      />
</>

}
```

***Options***

```
const districtOptions = [
    { value: "ciutatvella", label: "Ciutat Vella" },
    { value: "gracia", label: "Gràcia" },
    { value: "eixample", label: "L'Eixample" },
    { value: "sarria", label: "Sarrià" }
  ];
```

Any idea on what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

just in case some stumbles upon this: you have to use `defaultValue` of Autocomplete instead of the Controller

Answer (score 0):

Hey just use this package below:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mui-react-hook-form-plus

```
import { HookAutoComplete, useHookForm } from 'mui-react-hook-form-plus ';

const Component = () => {
    const {registerState, handleSubmit} = useHookForm({
        defaultValues: { movie: '' },
    });
    
    const onSubmit = (data: typeof defaultValues) => {
        // will run if it is valid
    }
    
    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            <HookAutoComplete
                    {...registerState('movie')}
                    autocompleteProps={{
                        options: ['Fight Club', 'Top Gun', 'Titanic']
                    }}
                    textFieldProps={{
                        label: 'Movie',
                        placeholder: 'search...',
                    }}
                />
            <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
        </form>
    )
}
```

#### [See Demo](https://mui-react-hook-form-plus.vercel.app/?path=/docs/hookautocomplete-%E2%8C%A8--hookautocomplete-%F0%9F%9B%AB)